# When I change state at project this state should be marked with a date when it was changed Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have interface of Project, that into this is variable state declared like number. But how it is possible when state changes to add a date for every change.

This is interface

```
export interface Project {
state: number;
}
```

This is when I edit the project

```
 <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start start" fxLayoutGap="15px">
      <app-dropdown [(ngModel)]="editProject.state" label="Project State" labelWidth="100px" optionWidth="250px" orientation="top"
        [items]="projectState" (click)="changeStatesAndTypes()"></app-dropdown>
    </div>
```

This is the changeStateAndTypes method.

```
changeStatesAndTypes() {
  if (this.editProject.type === 2) {
      this.projectState = [{key: 0, value: 'Published'}];
      this.editProject.state = 0;
  }  if (this.editProject.state === 0) {
    this.projectType =
     [{key: 0, value: 'Approved'},
     {key: 1, value: 'Denied'},
     {key: 2, value: 'Waiting for Approval'},
     {key: 4, value: 'ReDo'}];
  }  if (this.editProject.type === 0) {
    this.projectState = [{key: 2, value: 'In progress'}];
    this.editProject.state = 2;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you show your changeStatesAndTypes() ?

Comment: I edited the question there are changeStateAndTypes, because state and types are depending from each other

Comment: Have io tried this?
this.editProject.state = +new Date();

Comment: No I didn't, how do you recommend me to do this, because I have interface declared like number should I change there something ?
I tried now but i can't save Error 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Change your interface to Date if you want to pass date to your state

Comment: Yeah but then the state will not show because is declared like number not like date ??